# Push Notifications Chrome (register and wait notifications)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, push-api

Following [this tutorial](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web) I am trying to register my chrome browser to the GCM but I can't subscribe the browser:

I am trying to do the same as the following examples without the button. Once you accept the permision request, I want to get the subscription id but it doesn't work:

- [Example 1](https://askibinski.github.io/)
- [Example 2](https://simple-push-demo.appspot.com/)

Here is the project if you want to check the code:

- [The project](https://github.com/watzenare/watzenare.github.io)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the example project you give is that the Service Worker never gets ready.

This is due to the location of your service worker js file. It is stored in the `js` directory, so its scope are only the pages located in this directory, and the page requesting for the service worker is in the root dir.

To make a service worker available for the whole site, you must put it in the site's root directory.

According to the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#navigator-service-worker-register), you can also set the Service Worker's scope manually by setting the `scopeURL` option in the `navigator.serviceWorker.register()` call.

Answer (score 1):

There is this one I found:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/push-notificatons-on-the-open-web?hl=en

Which seems to have a step by step implementation guide to push notification.

Comment: there are some examples like that but it doesn't show how to get the subscriptionId that it's the first step once accepted push on the browser. thank you for your help!